# TypeError Object of type set is not JSON serializable in Python RestAPI

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo, flask-restful

I was trying to build a RestAPI to find a user and update new fields of data in mongodb, But i have encountered an error while compiling, I got the following error

raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

below code is my app.py file

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request 
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
cluster = MongoClient("my cluster")
db  = cluster["my_db"]
col = db["user"]

class datadetail(Resource):
    def post(self):
        input_data = request.get_json()
        if input_data == None:
            return jsonify({"Sucess":False , "message": "wrong input parameter"})
    
        elif 'ID' not in input_data:
            return jsonify({"Sucess":False,"message":"ID missing"})
        else:
            result = col.find_one({"ID" : input_data['ID']})
            if not result:
               return jsonify({"ID is not matching"})
            else:
               col.find_one_and_update({'ID':input_data['ID']}, {'$push':{"Details1": input_data["Details1"],"data2": input_data["data2"] ,"data3": input_data["data3"] ,"data4": input_data["data4"]}})
       
        
api.add_resource(datadetail, '/datadetail')           
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

below is my input_data json structure:
{
"ID": "dfghj",
"Details1": "Details1",
"data2": "xyz123",
"data3": "data3",
"data4": "data4"
}

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are getting is due to the fact that you are trying to serialize an object of type 'set' which is not supported by JSON.
You can fix this error by changing the data type of the object you are trying to serialize from 'set' to 'list'. You can do this by using the 'list()' function.

```
For example:
list(input_data["data4"])
```

complete line with the fix

```
col.find_one_and_update({'ID':input_data['ID']}, {'$push':{"Details1": input_data["Details1"],"data2": input_data["data2"] ,"data3": input_data["data3"] ,"data4": list(input_data["data4"])}})
```

This should fix your error and allow you to serialize the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a cool trick to make a json string from any dict (or dict-like structure).

Remember that in python you can pass into the dict any type, but for json there are only str* available (but sometimes not only [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html))

OK assume that `flask.jsonfy()` is almost the same thing as `json.dumps()`

[os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) returns all about environ. But this object despite the fact that it looks like `dict` but **it is not JSON-serializable**

```py
import os
import json

# it is my case
env = os.environ
json.dumps(env)  # it causes error

# the solution is cast to dict all the objects:
env = os.environ
json.dumps(dict(**env))  # this doesn't have error
```

If this is not helpful, you can force cast to string all the elements:

```py
json.dumps({str(key): str(value) for key, value in your_dict.items()})
# or in your case 
flask.jsonify({str(key): str(value) for key, value in your_dict.items()})
```

Hope it helps.